# TypeScript: check of `unknown` argument - are `undefined` and `null` different cases?

Tags: typescript

Code inspection (IntelliJ and GitHub) says that the following code can be simplified:

```js
type Something = string | number | boolean | object
function isSomething(a: unknown): a is Something {
    return a != undefined && a != null;
}
```

because `a != null` is always `true`. Why is that? AFAIK `undefined` and `null` are different values.

Comment: `null == undefined` is `true`. If you really need to distinguish `undefined` and `null`, use the `===` and `!==` operators.

Answer (score 3):

`a != undefined` is false if `a` is null. That means if `a` is `null`, the second condition will never run, since the `&&` operator will short-circuit.

```js
console.log(null == undefined); // true
console.log(null != undefined); // false
```